# Delphi TFDTable open fails when indexname is set

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

Using Delphi 10.3.3, mainly under Windows10, I have a number of [FireDAC] TFDTable components accessing an SQL Server DB.

Everything worked fine in delphi 10.2.3 but in the Rio version, I find that those TFDtables which have an indexname set and which **access a DB whose name has a space in it**, fail with the message "[FireDAC]{DatS]-2 Object [PK_DEPT] is not found."

An example of the table definition in the dfm is:

```
  object tbHODEPT: TFDTable
    IndexName = 'PK_DEPT'
    ConnectionName = 'HEADOFFICE'
    FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode]
    FetchOptions.Mode = fmAll
    UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName = 'DEPT'
    TableName = 'DEPT'
```

The connection, "HEADOFFICE", is a TFDConnection descendant which just adds the credentials for the relevant DB at open-time. I have noticed that if I supply a fully qualified TableName property (e.g. '[Some DBname].dbo.[DEPT') then the problem does not occur. But setting the DBname at design time is undesirable as we allow the DB names to be configurable.

Barring a solution, my options seem to be

- Renaming the problematic DB, and
- Changing all of the affected TFDTables to use indexfieldnames instead. (This works OK).

Ideas welcome.